# Having issues with getting VueJS to accept dynamic image string

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I have seen a few questions similar to this but all revolve around webpack, which I am not currently using.

I have a Vue template:

```
    var question = Vue.component('question', {
    props: {
        scenario: { type: Object }
    },
    beforeMount: function () {
        this.retrieveScenario();
    },
    methods: {
        postChoice: function () {
            Post("Study", "PostScenarioChoice")
        },
        retrieveScenario: function () {
            Get("ScenariosVue", "GetScenario", 1, this,
                (c, data) => { this.scenario = data; },
                (c, errors) => { console.log(errors); }
            );
        }
    },

    template:
        `<div class="visible">
                <div class="row justify-content-center">
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <a v-on:click="this.postChoice">
                            <img class="img-fluid" v-bind:src="scenario.scenarioLeftImg" />
                        </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <a v-on:click="this.postChoice">
                        <img class="img-fluid" v-bind:src="scenario.scenarioLeftImg" />
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div >`

});
```

The Ajax retrieval returns an object with the following:

```
returned 
Object { 
    scenarioId: 1, 
    description: "Dog vs Bolard", 
    scenarioLeftImg: "images\\Scenarios\\bolard_dog_Left.png", 
    scenarioRightImg: "images\\Scenarios\\bolard_dog_Right.png",
    participantScenarios: [], 
    scenarioTypesScenarios: [] 
}
```

However, the Html, doesn't add the src tag to the  tag and I'm really not sure why because the data's clearly available.

Much Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have **backslashes** in your `src`. Replace those by **slashes**.

Comment: Hi @connexo, done that but hasn't worked i'm afraid

Comment: Pick your answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because Vue's template system doesn't "watch" properties (or nested properties) of an object for changes. If you need to do this, then you can either use the `computed` property with a `watch` on the computed property, or you can just create two `props` instead of the single `prop`. Here is what I would do to change your code:

```js
var question = Vue.component('question', {
  props: {
    // Replace this prop with the two below.
    // scenario: { type: Object }
    scenarioLeftImg: { type: String },
    scenarioRightImg: { type: String }
  },
  beforeMount: function () {
    this.retrieveScenario();
  },
  methods: {
    postChoice: function () {
      Post("Study", "PostScenarioChoice")
    },
    retrieveScenario: function () {
      Get("ScenariosVue", "GetScenario", 1, this,
        (c, data) => { this.scenario = data; },
        (c, errors) => { console.log(errors); }
      );
    }
  },
  template:
    `<div class="visible">
      <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <a v-on:click="this.postChoice">
            <img class="img-fluid" v-bind:src="scenarioLeftImg" />
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <a v-on:click="this.postChoice">
            <img class="img-fluid" v-bind:src="scenarioLeftImg" />
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div >`
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your main issue is that due to the limitations of Javascript, [Vue cannot detect property additions in Objects](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html).

Change to

```
retrieveScenario: function () {
        Get("ScenariosVue", "GetScenario", 1, this,
            (c, data) => { Vue.set(this.data, 'scenarios', data); },
            (c, errors) => { console.log(errors); }
        );
    }
```

Please be aware that it is considered really bad practice to have components modify their `props`. Rather mirror those props into your vm's data() function in the `created()` hook of your component, then modify that. If you need the "modified" props outside of your component, emit an event telling those components props has changed.

Also replace the backslashes in your path by slashes:

```
scenarioLeftImg: "images\\Scenarios\\bolard_dog_Left.png", 
scenarioRightImg: "images\\Scenarios\\bolard_dog_Right.png",
```

has to be

```
scenarioLeftImg: "images/Scenarios/bolard_dog_Left.png", 
scenarioRightImg: "images/Scenarios/bolard_dog_Right.png",
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to have worked. If there is a different implementation you think suits better, please let me know. I am very new to Vue and also complex JS as a whole.

Comment: I'm afraid that to work with complex stuff needs you diving into the complexity - there's no way around that, but Vue.js makes this considerably less painful than e.g. Angular or React...

Comment: Hi @connexo i completely understand, just wondering if you think i'm going down the completely wrong path or if it is correct just needs tweaking and if so how?

Comment: First and foremost stop manipulating `props` inside components. Props should be considered read-only inside the component.

Comment: Do everything connexo says, then ask yourself "why am I modifying a property?" Components should not modify their properties. If your component looks after it's own state then your scenario object should be in the data.